# geom_smooth with string in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a variable I want to use for the y-axis in ggplots, which must be passed as its "" name (for reasons like, I could use a few variables there and want a changing y-axis label to reflect it).

But I also want to plot a smoothed line on the graph.

```
ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, col=Species)) +
  geom_point(aes_string(y="Petal.Length")) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~x, se=F)
```

gives `Error: stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: y`. Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: `geom_smooth` is not passed a y variable. Something like this would pass the y variable, however I'm not sure what your want. `ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=as.character(Petal.Length), col=Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~x, se=F)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `help('get')`? It will

> Return the Value of a Named Object

and use it as the `y` coordinate to plot the data.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y = get("Petal.Length"), color=Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~x, se=F)
```

[image]